# Could not find devise mapping for path "/hotels/9/users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

**Context**

I implemented devise & devise_invitable where a user.admin can have many hotels and subsequently can invite a user to s specific hotel.

**Issue**

I would like to generate an index page of all the users belonging to a hotel (whether they accepted the invitation or not). Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/hotels/9/users". 
This may happen for two reasons: 
1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: 
devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 
2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. 
If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:
 @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

**Code**

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

  resources :hotels do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users' }
    resources :users, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

rails routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                  Controller#Action
                               new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                     devise/sessions#new
                                   user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                     devise/sessions#create
                           destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                    devise/sessions#destroy
                              new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#new
                             edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                               devise/passwords#edit
                                  user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#update
                                                PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#update
                                                POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#create
                       cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                      devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
                          new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                     devise_invitable/registrations#new
                         edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                        devise_invitable/registrations#edit
                              user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                             devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                                PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                             devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                                DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                             devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
                                                POST   /users(.:format)                                                                             devise_invitable/registrations#create
                         accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                           devise/invitations#edit
                         remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                           devise/invitations#destroy
                            new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#new
                                user_invitation PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                                                                  devise/invitations#update
                                                PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                                                                  devise/invitations#update
                                                POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                                                                  devise/invitations#create
                          new_user_hotel_session GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/sign_in(.:format)                                                      devise/sessions#new
                              user_hotel_session POST   /users/hotels/:hotel_id/sign_in(.:format)                                                      devise/sessions#create
                      destroy_user_hotel_session DELETE /users/hotels/:hotel_id/sign_out(.:format)                                                     devise/sessions#destroy
                         new_user_hotel_password GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/password/new(.:format)                                                 devise/passwords#new
                        edit_user_hotel_password GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/password/edit(.:format)                                                devise/passwords#edit
                             user_hotel_password PATCH  /users/hotels/:hotel_id/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#update
                                                PUT    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#update
                                                POST   /users/hotels/:hotel_id/password(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#create
                  cancel_user_hotel_registration GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/cancel(.:format)                                                       devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
                     new_user_hotel_registration GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/sign_up(.:format)                                                      devise_invitable/registrations#new
                    edit_user_hotel_registration GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/edit(.:format)                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#edit
                         user_hotel_registration PATCH  /users/hotels/:hotel_id(.:format)                                                              devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                                PUT    /users/hotels/:hotel_id(.:format)                                                              devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                                DELETE /users/hotels/:hotel_id(.:format)                                                              devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
                                                POST   /users/hotels/:hotel_id(.:format)                                                              devise_invitable/registrations#create
                    accept_user_hotel_invitation GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation/accept(.:format)                                            users#edit
                    remove_user_hotel_invitation GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation/remove(.:format)                                            users#destroy
                       new_user_hotel_invitation GET    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation/new(.:format)                                               users#new
                           user_hotel_invitation PATCH  /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation(.:format)                                                   users#update
                                                PUT    /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation(.:format)                                                   users#update
                                                POST   /users/hotels/:hotel_id/invitation(.:format)                                                   users#create
                                     hotel_users GET    /hotels/:hotel_id/users(.:format)                                                              users#index
```

models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_hotels
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :admin
  end

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end

class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_hotels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end
```

controller

```
class UsersController < Devise::InvitationsController
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index

  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = @hotel.users.new
    authorize @user
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = @hotel.users.new(hotel_user_params)
    @user.user_hotels.build(hotel: @hotel)
    authorize @user
    if @user.invite!
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @users = @hotel.users
    authorize @users
    @users = policy_scope(@users)
  end

  private
  def hotel_user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :role,
      user_hotels_attributes: [:hotel_id,
        hotel_attributes:[:name, :slug, :description, :street, :street_number, :zipcode, :city, :country, :email, :phone, :website, :vat_number, :currency, :photo, :test_modus, :default_vat, :price_notation, :paytime, :billing_id, :default_hotel_language, :default_age_table]])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please show an output of `rails routes`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will update the question with the routes

Comment: Fixed it, by creating a seperate invitable_controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue, by creating a seperate devise_invitable controller. Thereby using the users_controller for the index action.